# PHP PDO SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've looked around the internet and haven't been able to resolve this issue.

I'm trying to insert a row into a mySQL table using PDO through this function

```
function newItem($name, $desc, $price, $catID){
    echo $name . "\n";
    echo $price . "\n";
    echo $desc . "\n";
    echo $catID . "\n";

    $conn = self::connect();
    //INSERT Order
    $sql = "INSERT INTO catalogue (Name, Price, CatID, Desc)
    VALUES ('$name', $price, $catID, '$desc')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);

}
```

when i do, i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Desc) VALUES ('User', 0.00, 3, 'theUser')' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\catalogue.php:65 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\catalogue.php(65): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO cat...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\main.php(39): Catalogue->newItem('User', 'theUser', '0.00', '3') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\catalogue.php on line 65
```

I can confirm that the `self::connect();` method works, and the problem only occurs when i try to insert data into the Desc column.

I've spent a good while trying to sort this issue, however my knowledge of PDO is quite vague....

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

the `echo`'s show this:

```
User 0.00 theUser 3
```

Comment: `Desc` is reserved keyword in mysql in must be in backtick https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html and use prepare and bind statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DESC` is a keyword. You have to escape the column Name using backtics or better rename the column.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalogue (Name, Price, CatID, `Desc`)
    VALUES ('$name', $price, $catID, '$desc')";
```

For more Information about keywords see the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

Comment: I'll mark this as correct in 9 minutes, thanks, and your edit came just in time, i was just about to post a comment asking if "description" is a keyword xD

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the answer itself. It's just my humble attempt to fix the [bike shed problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange). Disclaimer: I will not engage in any further discussion on the matter.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the Explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`Desc` is reserved keyword in mysql in must be in backtick https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.html and use prepare and bind statement

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO catalogue (Name, Price, CatID, `Desc`)
    VALUES (:Name, :Price, :CatID, :Desc)");
$sth->bindParam(':Name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':Price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':CatID', $catID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':Desc', $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: what are the benefits of this over the method i used?

Comment: TO prevent form sql injection. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Except `:CatID` should probably be `PDO::PARAM_INT` - but yeah, it's better to go with prepared statements with bound parameters over raw SQL.

Comment: Yaa correct @CD001

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalogue (Name, Price, CatID, Desc)
    VALUES ('".$name."', $price, $catID, '".$desc."')";
```

Comment: Neither solves the problem nor explains what you've done or why.